# Access to hyperlink in listview in Itemtemplate

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to access a `hyperlink` on my `listview`. When the user logs in,
the hyperlink will show on my homepage. It doesn't show.

```
protected void lvtop6_ItemCommand(object sender, ListViewCommandEventArgs e)
{

    ListView hlBuy = (ListView)lvtop6.FindControl("hlBuy");

    if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated==true)
    {
        hlBuy.Visible = true;
    }
    else
    {
        hlBuy.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

Please somebody advise me to figure out what is wrong with my code behind

Comment: Without more information, my guess is that lvtop6_ItemCommand is never called...

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you're trying to set visible: your Hyperlink or your ListView.

You've cast a control to type ListView, but your Hungarian notation seems to suggest that it's a hyperlink. **Update your question with more details**, and we can get it sorted out.

Does `lvtop6_ItemCommand()` ever get called? Can you set a breakpoint in that code?

Meanwhile, try to simplify your 5 lines of code into 1:

```
hlBuy.Visible = User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
```

Perhaps you need to cast your hyperlink:

```
HyperLink hlBuy = (HyperLink)lvtop6.FindControl("hlBuy");
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to set visible my Hyperlink in my listview(lvtop6) the reason of why I'm doing this is when a user logged in then the hyperlink (hlBuy) will appear on my homepage.
I'm not sure about that event I'm using lvtop6_ItemCommand() because when I set breakpoint nothing happend I've tried Databound events either but it did'nt work.